# .kill() in python subprocess kills parent rather than child process

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm attempting to open a child process of a second python script in the function below. It seems to open the process fine, but when I attempt to end the process, the parent process terminates and the child process persists. Any recommendations on why this may be happening?

```
def thermostat(input):
global ThermostatRunning
global proc
print("Thermostat Function input: %s" % input)
if input == 'stop' and ThermostatRunning == 1:
    print("test")
    proc.kill()
    print proc.poll()
    dev2(0) #ensure heater is off
    return('Thermostat turned off')
elif input=='stop' and ThermostatRunning == 0:
    status = "Thermostat already stopped"
    print(status)
    return(status)
if input.isdigit() == 0:
        return("Thermostat input is not a number or -stop-")
if ThermostatRunning == 1:
    print("test2")
    proc.kill()
print("test3")
proc = subprocess.Popen('python thermostat.py -t %s' % input, shell=True)#, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
ThermostatRunning = 1
#for line in proc.stdout.readlines():
    #print (line)
status = "Thermostat started with set temperature: %s" % input
print(status)
return(status)
```

The only other issue that may be pertinent is that this is a flask script. I'm not sure if that changes anything.

Comment: how are you calling this function exactly (from a separate module, class, file, etc?). In general I'd recommend putting this within a class and trying to avoid the use of globals, though I'm not sure if this is related to the issue you're running into.

Comment: I'm calling from another function within the same file. I'm quite new to python and don't have much experience with classes yet.

Comment: Is `python thermostat.py` a placeholder for some other process? Otherwise, why do you need `shell=True`? `Popen([sys.executable or 'python', '-mthermostat', '-t', input])` should work without shell. Do you need it to be a separate process? Have you tried `from thermostat import some_function; some_function(input)`?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian The main script is a web interface for multiple other tasks. I need to be able to call a URL and start this second script, thermostat.py, and for it to be able to run constantly in the background but the main script to continue and remain responsive. I'll play around with not using shell=true.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the subprocess with shell=True, you actually spawn a process that spawns another subprocess, so when you call proc.kill(), you're only killing the parent process.  You want to make your subprocess the process group leader so you can kill them all at once.

Uncomment the setsid in the Popen call and kill the whole process group like so:

```
os.killpg(proc.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

Comment: Yeah, that's one of the things I tried to get it working, but that seems to kill both. Is it possible to use this method to kill ONLY the child process?
Thanks!

Comment: @brett: have you forgot to uncomment `setsid`?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian no, that is uncommented.